# Windows 8.1 Won't Login Until It Connects To A Network

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, login

I have a custom built PC* running Windows 8.1 Pro. My account is a local account, *not* an online account. While my computer takes about fifteen seconds to boot, it takes about another ten to fifteen to connect to the Ethernet network, (and I tried this on two separate networks, one at home and one at school) and even more strange is the fact that the computer won't login *until* it has connected. It doesn't give an error, it just hangs with the login wheel spinning until the network is connected and then it logs in. If I wait for the network to connect first it will log in instantly. I've looked on the internet and have found no other reports of this and I have run the typical malwarebytes/ccleaner/etc. I reinstalled the LAN drivers which didn't help, however in that process I needed to restart my computer with the LAN driver uninstalled and it still wouldn't login without a network connection. (I luckily have a wifi adapter too) The issue has been around for about half a year and I've had the computer for about a year, so it wasn't always like this and I don't remember doing anything before it happened. While the issue isn't critical, I'd definitely appreciate if anyone has any input. Thanks!

*Details
Motherboard: Asrock Fatal1ty Z87 Killer
Processor: Intel i7 4770k
RAM: 8GB (Team Elite, 1 Stick)
GPU: NVidia GTX 660 (EVGA)
Disks: 64GB SSD (Windows) + 2TB HDD (Documents/Program Files)

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back to a previous system restore point, I faced computers with similar issues in the past and that's resolved it. Pick one that's before the date when the problem first occured

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any restore points that far back. :/

Comment: Try doing a windows repair then?

Comment: I think I tried that as well, but as with the LAN drivers I'll try again just to double check.

Comment: I only saw startup repair, and that didn't help. Neither did installing the LAN drivers.